# "end()" iterator for back inserters?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

For iterators such as those returned from `std::back_inserter()`, is there something that can be used as an "end" iterator?

This seems a little nonsensical at first, but I have an API which is:

```
template<typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator>
void foo(
    InputIterator input_begin,
    InputIterator input_end,
    OutputIterator output_begin,
    OutputIterator output_end
);
```

`foo` performs some operation on the input sequence, generating an output sequence. (Who's length is known to `foo` but may or may not be equal to the input sequence's length.)

The taking of the `output_end` parameter is the odd part: `std::copy` doesn't do this, for example, and assumes you're not going to pass it garbage. `foo` does it to provide range checking: if you pass a range too small, it throws an exception, in the name of defensive programming. (Instead of potentially overwriting random bits in memory.)

Now, say I want to pass `foo` a back inserter, specifically one from a `std::vector` which has no limit outside of memory constraints. I still need a "end" iterator - in this case, something that will never compare equal. (Or, if I had a `std::vector` but with a restriction on length, perhaps it might sometimes compare equal?)

How do I go about doing this? I do have the ability to change `foo`'s API - is it better to not check the range, and instead provide an alternate means to get the required output range? (Which would be needed anyways for raw arrays, but not required for back inserters into a vector.) This would seem less robust, but I'm struggling to make the "robust" (above) work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `foo` is checking to ensure that `distance(output_begin, output_end)` is sufficiently large to contain the results, what could you use as an "end" iterator?  A `back_inserter` adds elements to the end; the `distance` between the place at which a `back_inserter` adds elements and the end of the sequence is, by definition, `0`.

A `foo` with the `std::copy`-like signature `foo(InIt, InIt, OutIt)` is, in my opinion, your best option.  It isn't really "not robust."  For most algorithms, you only want to do this kind of range checking in debug builds for performance reasons, and a decent Standard Library implementation (like the Visual C++ Standard Library) will already provide a lot of range checking in debug builds.

Alternatively, you could create a `back_inserting_foo(InIt, InIt, Container)`, though creating a special case for this would be a bit unusual and places a greater burden upon users of the function to know which overload they need to use for different types of iterators.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid changing `foo()`'s API by performing the safety check as you go, by checking that `curr_output_iter != output_end` before each element is written out (see below), instead of once at the start with a `distance()` check as [James McNellis suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573496/end-iterator-for-back-inserters/4573509#4573509).

Doing this will require writing your own "iterator adaptor" to provide an "enhanced" output iterator that can test for whether it's at the end of its valid range.  Then you would rightfully change the template typenames from `OutputIterator` to `SafeOutputIterator` -- even though this just serves as documentation because it's something that can't be enforced in C++.  We distinguish between "bounded" and "unbounded" iterator pairs: for the latter, no two iterators will ever compare equal, and in fact the 2nd iterator will never be needed for anything besides its type.

```
/* Metafunction for determining whether the range has a fixed endpoint.
 * Assume all iterators are bounded except for OutputIterators. */
template <typename Tag>
struct helper {
    static bool value = true;
};

template <>
struct helper<output_iterator_tag> {
    static bool value = false;
};

template <typename It>
struct is_bounded {
    static bool value = helper<typename iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category>::value;
};

/* Wraps an output iterator. */
template<typename It, bool BOUNDED = is_bounded<It>::value>
class safe_output_iterator {
    typedef typename iterator_traits<It>::value_type value_type;

public:
    explicit safe_output_iterator(It iter, size_t limit = 0) : iter_(iter), limit_(limit) {}

    safe_output_iterator& operator++() {  /* Preinc */
        ++iter_;
        return *this;
    }

    safe_output_iterator operator++(int) {  /* Postinc */
        safe_output_iterator temp(*this);
        ++iter_;
        return temp;
    }

    /* Trick: Deferencing returns the same object, so that operator=() works */
    safe_output_iterator& operator*() {
        return *this;
    }

    /* Will be called despite "dereferencing" this iterator object */
    safe_output_iterator& operator=() {
        /* Insert check for limit == 0 here if you want */
        --limit_;
        return *_iter;
    }

    /* Addition to the OutputIterator concept. */
    bool operator==(safe_output_iterator const& x) {
        return BOUNDED && limit_ == x.limit_;
    }

    bool operator!=(safe_output_iterator const& x) {
        return !(*this == x);
    }

private:
    It iter_;
    size_t limit_;
};

/* Helper function templates to avoid typing out long typenames */

/* Handle iterators */
template <typename It>
safe_output_iterator<It> soi_begin(It it, size_t limit = 0) {
    return safe_output_iterator<It>(it, limit);
}

template <typename It>
safe_output_iterator<It> soi_end(It it, size_t limit = 0) {
    return safe_output_iterator<It>(it, limit);
}

/* Handle STL containers like vector and list */
template <typename C>
safe_output_iterator<It> soi_begin_cont(C cont) {
    return safe_output_iterator<typename C::iterator>(cont.begin(), cont.size());
}

template <typename C>
safe_output_iterator<It> soi_end_cont(C cont) {
    /* Actually the iterator supplied (here cont.end()) is unimportant... */
    return safe_output_iterator<typename C::iterator>(cont.end());
}
```

You can now write code like:

```
vector<int> u(10, 42), v(ENOUGH_SPACE), w, x(ENOUGH_SPACE);

// Explicit iterator pair; bounded
foo(u.begin(), u.end(), soi_begin(v.begin(), ENOUGH_SPACE), soi_end(v));

// Explicit iterator pair; unbounded (2nd iterator ignored, but we need the type)
foo(u.begin(), u.end(), soi_begin(w.back_inserter()), soi_end(w.back_inserter()));

// Use whole container
foo(u.begin(), u.end(), soi_begin_cont(x), soi_end_cont(x));
```

You can either have `foo()` check `curr_output_iter != output_end` before each write through `*curr_output_iter`, or alternatively insert the check in `safe_output_iterator::operator=()`.  The latter seems preferable as you then cannot forget to perform the check whenever a pair of `safe_output_iterator`s are passed to any arbitrary algorithm (presumably this is similar to how debug versions of the STL work).  You could also write overloads of `soi_begin_cont()` and `soi_end_cont()` for fixed-size arrays.

All this would be much less cumbersome if [ranges](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/range/index.html) were used by STL algorithms instead of iterator pairs -- that way a single function template could return an appropriate range spanning an entire array, for example.

Comment: This is a reasonable approach.  I hadn't thought of checking whether `out_it == out_end` in each iteration instead of computing the distance.  If the algorithm could be modified such that the two output iterators can be of different types (using two template parameters), this could be made easier by simply having a `back_inserter_end` iterator that, when compared against any iterator returns not equal.  That would make for much less code but is possibly messier.  I still don't think range checking like this is a great idea, but if it is really desired, this is a good way to accomplish it!

Comment: @James: That `back_inserter_end` iterator sounds tempting...  Would be nice if all iterators had a "NULL" value like pointers do, since that value could then be used instead of needing a separate type to hold it.  Oh well.

Comment: These are all excellent answers, and I wish I could mark "Accepted Answer" on more than one thing. I've upvoted yours (though I wish I could +2 it), but I'm giving James the Accepted Answer as that's the solution I'm going with. (this is going to be a library, so I'm not sure about exposing this in an external API) This was definitely informative and interesting - thank you for taking the time to post it.

Comment: @Thanatos: No problem, James's answer is good and I think mine is a bit overcomplicated anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment to j_random_hacker's answer, if you modify the algorithm such that the iterators passed to it can be of different types, for example,

```
template <typename InIt1, InIt2, OutIt1, OutIt2>
void foo(InIt1 in_begin, InIt2 in_end, OutIt1 out_begin, OutIt2 out_end) { }
```

then you can very easily write a `back_inserter_end` class to test against:

```
class back_inserter_end 
    : std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void>
{ };

bool operator==(back_inserter_end, back_inserter_end) { return true;  }
bool operator!=(back_inserter_end, back_inserter_end) { return false; }

template <typename Container>
bool operator==(const back_insert_iterator<Container>&, back_inserter_end) { 
     return false; 
}

template <typename Container>
bool operator==(back_inserter_end, const back_insert_iterator<Container>&) { 
    return false; 
}

template <typename Container>
bool operator!=(const back_insert_iterator<Container>&, back_inserter_end) { 
    return true; 
}

template <typename Container>
bool operator!=(back_inserter_end, const back_insert_iterator<Container>&) { 
    return true; 
}
```

You can then call your "safe" algorithm:

```
foo(it, it, std::back_inserter(v), back_inserter_end());
```

Inside of your "safe" algorithm, you can test whether `out_it == out_end` before using `out_it`; since `out_it` is a `back_insert_iterator`, this test will always return `false` (which is the desired behavior).

Comment: +1.  I'd be tempted to call this `endless_iterator` or `iterator_at_infinity` or somesuch as it's probably useful in a variety of contexts.

Comment: @j_random_hacker:  Yeah; it could be made less restrictive by changing the template parameter from `Container` to `Iterator and `back_insert_iterator<Container>` into `Iterator`.  If it was named `iterator_at_infinity`, I'd also want to overload `operator+` so that I could say `iterator_at_infinity() + 1` and iterate To Infinity And Beyond!  :-D